# Export Mathematica to $\LaTeX$ properly

Tags: latex, conversion, export

I am simply trying to convert an existing sample in *Mathematica* to $\LaTeX$. For example, if I open a new *Mathematica* notebook using styled templates such as Journal article and save it as $\TeX$. Compiling the $\TeX$ to PDF neglecting some minor errors, I can find a very ugly document.

One reason I realized that almost all block expressions are not properly (or fully) converted. For instance, \item is used without \begin{itemize} and \end{itemize}. A table Similarly, for multiline equations, figures and references.

An interesting thing is that it seems these block expressions are implemented in the stylesheet, JournalArticle.nb, as the definitions of StyleData like Item1, EquationGroup and so on. (Unfortunately, I could not find any  documentation about how to use them or about "ExtraCellGroupingRules" options and etc. used in the definition.)

I am wondering whether the $\LaTeX$ converting function in *Mathematica* is not polished as it is now, or I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!